# Recreating canva like section using React, Tailwind and Framer Motion

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, framer-motion

When I look at website: https://www.framer.com/ there're a section where user can move around the canvas and drag the element around. It's so impressive that I want to recreate it using their framework. Now this is my code

**Canvas.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { motion, useMotionValue, useTransform, useSpring } from "framer-motion";

interface CanvasProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  dragConstraints?: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
}

const Canvas = ({ children, dragConstraints }: CanvasProps) => {
  const x = useMotionValue(0);
  const y = useMotionValue(0);

  const springX = useSpring(x, { stiffness: 100, damping: 20 });
  const springY = useSpring(y, { stiffness: 100, damping: 20 });

  return (
    <motion.div
      drag
      dragElastic={0.1}
      dragMomentum={false}
      className="relative flex items-center justify-around w-screen min-h-screen bg-transparent cursor-pointer"
      onDragEnd={() => {
        x.set(0);
        y.set(0);
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default Canvas;
```

**Draggable.tsx**

```
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { useMotionValue, useTransform, useSpring } from "framer-motion";

interface DragableProps {
  constraintRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  x?: number;
  y?: number;
}

const Dragable = ({ constraintRef, children }: DragableProps) => {
  const x = useMotionValue(0);
  const y = useMotionValue(0);

  const springX = useSpring(x, { stiffness: 150, damping: 20 });
  const springY = useSpring(y, { stiffness: 150, damping: 20 });
  return (
    <div>
      <motion.div
        className="flex items-center justify-center cursor-move max-w-[10rem]"
        style={{ x: springX, y: springY }}
        drag
        dragElastic={0.1}
        dragMomentum={false}
        initial={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        dragConstraints={constraintRef}
      >
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dragable;
```

**App.tsx**

```
import "../dist/output.css";
import Canvas from "./components/Canvas";
import Dragable from "./components/Draggable";
import { useRef } from "react";
import Earth from "./assets/planet-earth.svg";
import Mercury from "./assets/planet-mercury.svg";
import Venus from "./assets/planet-venus.svg";

const images = [Earth, Mercury, Venus];

function App() {
  const constraintRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="overflow-hidden bg-slate-500">
      <div ref={constraintRef} className="overflow-hidden">
        <Canvas>
          {images.map((image) => (
            <Dragable constraintRef={constraintRef}>
              <div>
                <img src={image} alt="" className="pointer-events-none" />
              </div>
            </Dragable>
          ))}
        </Canvas>
      </div>
      <div className="min-h-screen bg-black"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Canvas.tsx is a drag element and has transparent bg so it's create a illusion like the user can move around the canva
Draggable on the another hand also have move around but I set the constraint so I can't move out the canvas
In the App.tsx here I tried to position them using flex and the elements seem to be inline but how do I make the Draggable component scatter around like in the original website? If anyone have any ideas please let me know!